# adding char[] to dynamic array and deallocate from a function

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, function-definition

I need some help since I'm new to c++, I have a homework question where we should read a name to a char[] and then place that input inside a dynamic array, sort the dynamic array, and then terminate the allocated memory. We have to work with a half-done written program and I don't think I'm getting the input incorrectly in the dynamic array and I have a problem with deallocating memory could someone help with some tips maybe? My contribution to the code is highlighted in **  ** thanks!

```
const int BUFLEN = 100; // Max length of reading buffer

void sort(char* friendList[], int n); // n is the number of elements
void print(char* friendList[], int n); // n is the number of elements
void terminate(char* friendList[], int n); // n is the number of elements

const int AMOUNT = 5;

int main()
{
    char* friends[AMOUNT]; // Dynamic array with AMOUNT pcs of string pointers
    char buff[BUFLEN] = { "" }; // Creates a string buffer (null terminated)
    int count = 0;

    while (count < AMOUNT) // enter AMOUNT number of friends
    {
        cout << "Name a friend: ";
        cin.getline(buff, BUFLEN); // Temporary reading into string buffer

        friends[count] = **new char[AMOUNT];**  //. . .  WRITE CODE allocating memory to the string
        
        // WRITE CODE that adds loaded name to current location in the dynamic array
        **strcpy(friends[count], buff);**
            ++count;
    }

    sort(friends, count); // Sorts the ‘count’ strings
    print(friends, count); // Prints the ‘count’ first names
    terminate(friends, count);// Releases all allocated memory space

    return 0;
}

void sort(char* friendList[], int n)
{
    // WRITE FUNCTION that sorts the strings in the friendList in alphabetical order!
    **int result;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            result = strcmp(friendList[j+1], friendList[j]);
                if (result < 0)
                    swap(friendList[j+1], friendList[j]);
        }
    }**
}

void print(char* friendList[], int n)
{
    // WRITE FUNCTION that prints ‘n’ names from the friendList on screen!
    **for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << friendList[i] << " " << i << endl;
    }**

}

void terminate(char* friendList[], int n)
{
    // WRITE FUNCTION that releases all dynamically allocated memory!
    **for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete friendList[i];
    }
    delete [] friendList;
    cout << "deleted! ";**
}
```

Comment: And here's an excellent example of why we should *never* be teaching new programmers dynamic memory allocation. Nothing about this assignment is fundamental to programming or computer science, nor is it in any way idiomatic C++, and the whole thing really serves as a "can you read the C++ standard" exercise but forced upon beginner students.

Comment: Recommendation: Pick one part of the problem (preferably a part you need in order to make other parts have a hope of succeeding, but often figuring out all of the A-before-Bs comes with experience) and attack it alone. Rarely is a computer program one big problem instead of a bunch of little problems ganging up on you, so isolate the little problems and solve them then take all of the little solutions and assemble them like Lego bricks into the big solution.

Comment: In this case, you can't do much verifying that the rest of the program works without `print`. But you can't `print` without an array`, so make a really dumb array with values you put in yourself. When you can print that, you can move on to letting the user put items in the array. Or you can move on to sorting, because often it is a lot easier to test the sorting on a known array that you control completely.

Comment: Thanks i have been trying to do that and when i run this program i can sort and print the names properly but in not really sure if this part is correct when allocating memory:  friends[count] = **new char[AMOUNT];**  //. . .  WRITE CODE allocating memory to the string
        
        // WRITE CODE that adds loaded name to current location in the dynamic array
        **strcpy(friends[count], buff);**
            ++count; and when I later on trying to delete [] I get some error on the Heap

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems with this code:

In `main()`:

- not validating that `cin.getline()` is successful before using the contents of `buff`.
- `AMOUNT` is the wrong size to use when allocating a new `char[]` to store in `friends[]`.  The correct size should be either `strlen(buff)+1` or `cin.gcount()`.

In `terminate()` (not to be confused with `std::terminate()`):

- `delete[]`'ing the input array itself, which was not allocated with `new[]` to begin with and thus must not be `delete[]`'ed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this statement

```
friends[count] = new char[AMOUNT];
```

you need to write

```
friends[count] = new char[strlen( buff ) + 1];
```

Pay attention to that the array `friends` itself is not allocated dynamically.  But each its element points to a dynamically allocated array. So the function `terminate` can look like

```
void terminate(char* friendList[], int n)
{
    // WRITE FUNCTION that releases all dynamically allocated memory!
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete [] friendList[i];
        friendList[i] = nullptr; 
    }
    cout << "deleted! ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vlad this helped a lot =)